# how to setup Decals in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, decal

I am trying to fake a shadow in 3D space. ShadowDirectionalLight does not suit my purposes, therefore I am gonna run a texture based animation.

I was thinking of using Decals for my animations. Can someone provide an example of how to use them? Creation and how render cycle should be constructed is puzzling to me. I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Decals) post but it seems out of date.